# Twilio status_callback_event setting, not working for me, Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, twilio, twilio-api

Running this code below. It always successfully calls the number and sends the completed status to the callback url, but it does not sent any status updates before that. I checked the logs and there is only one call to the api made, which is the completed status.

Any idea why this wouldn't work? Documentation says these are valid status values: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#request-parameters-call-status

Also on another possibly related note, setting the status_callback_method to "GET" doesn't seem to work either.

Relevant Code:

```
CLIENT.calls.create(to=phone_number,
                    from_=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    url=url,
                    method="GET",
                    status_callback=STATUS_CALLBACK_URL + call_uid,
                    status_callback_method="POST",
                    status_callback_event=["queued", "ringing", "in-progress", "completed", "busy", "failed", "no-answer", "canceled"]
                    )
```

I also used these as the callback events as defined here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter

```
status_callback_event=["queued", "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"]
```

Unfortunately neither list works for me, only notifies me of the completed status

Comment: Which version of the Twilio Python library are you using?

Comment: just needed to update to the latest twilio library :(, Somehow didn't have it. Thanks

Comment: No worries, I wondered if that was the issue as there are slightly different attribute names between libraries (though it's more consistent with the API now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And... the answer is, try using the latest twilio library first .

Answer (score 0):

The python library uses the REST API whereas the page you have referenced is for parameters sent by Twilio to your server when you receive an incoming call.

The call back events are different, and there is no need to append the call_uid to your callback URL. Twilio will send that with the rest of the request.

Documentation that should get you on the right track is [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter)

Comment: yeah I actually tried those first, and it didn't work for those either. I changed them back and it's the same issue with those as well. I will update my question to point that out.